# Ruby Unable to map values to array of hash, searching for alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of hashes:

```
data1 = [{:first => 1, :second => 'whatever'},{:first => 2, :second => 'something'}]

test_merge = {'whatever' => {:third => 1, :fourth => 1}, 'something' => {:third => 2, :fourth => 2}}
```

I want this output:

```
[{:first=>"MODIFIED", :second=>"whatever", :test_field=>"added", :third=>1, :fourth=>1, "sdsds"=>"sdsds", "2x4"=>8}, {:first=>"MODIFIED", :second=>"something", :test_field=>"added", :third=>2, :fourth=>2, "sdsds"=>"sdsds", "2x4"=>8}]
```

I did map and merge:

```
data2 = data1.map do |d|
    d[:test_field] = 'added'
    d[:first] = 'MODIFIED'
    d2 = test_merge[d[:second]]
    d = d.merge(d2)
    d['sdsds'] = 'sdsds'
    d['2x4'] = 2*4
  end
```

I got:

```
data1 #=> [{:first=>"MODIFIED", :second=>"whatever", :test_field=>"added"}, {:first=>"MODIFIED", :second=>"something", :test_field=>"added"}]
data2 #=> [8, 8]
```

This can be fixed if I do

```
data2 = data1.map do |d|
        d[:test_field] = 'added'
        d[:first] = 'MODIFIED'
        d2 = {:test_field_two => 'notadded'}
        d = d.merge(d2)
        d['sdsds'] = 'sdsds'
        d['2x4'] = 2*4
        d #or d=d
end
```

But why do I have to insert that `d` in the end (`d` or `d=d`)? It looks ugly to write `d` in the end. Isn't there an alternative way to do it, I want the exact output as mentioned above?

**Edit: 3 Jan 2017** (Don't read this edit if you are reading the question for first time, everything is mentioned above)

I have to necessarily use merge inside the `.map`, because I have got another hash as follows:

```
test_merge = {'whatever' => {:third => 1, :fourth => 1}, 'something' => {:third => 2, :fourth => 2}}
```

which needs to be merged like this inside the .each (merge doesn't work in .each unfortunately so I have to use map) or .map

```
d = d.merge(test_merge[d[:second]])
```

**Also `'2x4'` , `:first` and other keys are important which needs to be set/modified.**

And if I need to modify d[:first] , it should get modified.

I tried `.each` as mentioned by steve,

```
data1 = [{:first => 1, :second => 'whatever'},{:first => 2, :second => 'something'}]

    test_merge = {'whatever' => {:third => 1, :fourth => 1}, 'something' => {:third => 2, :fourth => 2}}
      data1.each do |d|
        d[:test_field] = 'added'
        d[:first] = 'MODIFIED'
        d2 = test_merge[d[:second]]
        d = d.merge(d2)
        d['sdsds'] = 'sdsds'
        d['2x4'] = 2*4
      end
```

And this is the result I got:

```
[{:first=>"MODIFIED", :second=>"whatever", :test_field=>"added"}, {:first=>"MODIFIED", :second=>"something", :test_field=>"added"}]
```

That is not my expected output. Is there any hack to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing a `map` with a block the last executed line of the block is what's returned in the new array.

So if the last line is...

```
d['2x4'] = 2*4
```

Then it's 2*4 (8) that's returned.

Setting the last line of the block to...

```
d
```

...means that the value of the `d` variable (the entire hash) is returned.

You don't need to use `map` if you just want to change the hashes and don't need an array returned.  Use `each` instead. (Edited to take into account Eric's observation about shallow duplication).

```
data2 = data1.map{|d| d.dup}
data2.each do |d|
  d[:test_field] = 'added'
  d[:test_field_two] = 'notadded'
  d['sdsds'] = 'sdsds'
  d['2x4'] = 2*4
end
```

Comment: `isn't there an alternative way to do it ?` :)

Comment: Yes, don't use `map`.  Use `each` instead. See my edited revised answer.

Comment: I think `map` purpose is to avoid using `dup` and `each`.

Comment: @EricDuminil could be. I like your answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting to see how convoluted code in the question can lead to convoluted answers :)

Comment: `dup` isn't enough in this case BTW, data1 and data2 hashes are the same objects. Modifying data2 automatically modifies data1. You'd need `deep_dup`, which is now a deprecated Rails method.

Comment: @EricDuminil good point, but question isn't tagged with `rails` so `deep_dup` isn't available.  Still makes your answer better. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer steve, but I forgot to add tag `rails` , I am using rails 4.2, but I want to ask a question, if I use each instead of map, will I still be able to modify `d[:first] = 'some other value'` instead of `1` (or 2 in second hash) which is previously set on the hash? (you can see that d[:first] and d[:second] are already set, basically what if I want to modify it one day inside the `each`, will it be possible? )

Comment: Edit: I tested, I have to use a merge in the each, it doesn't work with merge. It does work if I set each hash individually but that seems to be tedious because I have lot of hashes, I have to use one more .each inside the .each      to merge

Comment: Edit: Please see my edited question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

[`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) returns a merged Hash without changing the original one, so you can add new `|key,value|` pairs and return the desired hash directly :

```
data2 = data1.map do |h1|
  h1.merge(:test_field     => 'added',
           :test_field_two => 'not_added',
           'sdsds'         => 'sdsds',
           '2x4'           => 2 * 4)
end
```

`data2` is now :

```
[{:first=>1,
  :second=>"whatever",
  :test_field=>"added",
  :test_field_two=>"not_added",
  "sdsds"=>"sdsds",
  "2x4"=>8},
 {:first=>2,
  :second=>"something",
  :test_field=>"added",
  :test_field_two=>"not_added",
  "sdsds"=>"sdsds",
  "2x4"=>8}]
```

while `data1` still is :

```
[{:first=>1, :second=>"whatever"}, {:first=>2, :second=>"something"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be better! Though I am not really sure if i understood the question correctly. Hope this helps.

```
data1 = [{:first => 1, :second => 'whatever'},{:first => 2, :second => 'something'}]

d2 = {:test_field_two => 'notadded', "sdsds"=>"sdsds", "2x4"=>2*4}

data2 = data1.map do |d| d.merge(d2) end

#=> [{:first=>1, :second=>"whatever", :test_field_two=>"notadded", "sdsds"=>"sdsds", "2x4"=>8}, {:first=>2, :second=>"something", :test_field_two=>"notadded", "sdsds"=>"sdsds", "2x4"=>8}]
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand it correctly. In the question, `data1` isn't changed, `data2` is the new array of hashes. You modify `data1`